# Apply function contain external library in pandas: How to make it faster?

Tags: pandas, numpy, pyspark, time-complexity, vectorization

I have dataframe  where the number of rows is around 9 million rows, contain Lattitude and longitude  as follows:

[image]

and I tried to obtain the nearest node and the distance to the nearest node for each point by using OSMnx library, through apply the following code:

```
def nearest_node(Lat,Lon):
    nearest_node,dist=ox.get_nearest_node(G, (Lat,Lon), return_dist=True)  
    return nearest_node 
def dist_to_Nnode(Lat,Lon):
    nearest_node,dist=ox.get_nearest_node(G, (Lat,Lon), return_dist=True)
    return dist 


df['nearest_node'] = np.vectorize(nearest_node)(df['Lat'],df['Lon'])
    
df['dist_to_Nnode'] = np.vectorize(dist_to_Nnode)(df['Lat'],df['Lon'])
```

where `G` is the network graph  and obtained by the following Codeline:

```
import osmnx as ox 
import networkx as nx
import os 


os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] =r'C:\Users\****\Anaconda3\Library\share'
import osmnx as ox
Graph_x= ox.graph_from_place('Beijing, China',  which_result=2)
G= ox.project_graph(Graph_x,to_crs={'proj':'longlat','epsg':'32750' ,'ellps':'WGS84', 'datum':'WGS84'}) #wgs 84 50S
```

I applied the previous code on a sample of the `df` where it already gave the desired result, but it spend a lot of time for the total `df`.
How to run this code faster??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [OSMnx documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils.get_nearest_nodes), use `ox.get_nearest_nodes(G, X, Y, method='kdtree')` where G is your projected graph and X and Y are vectors of your projected x and y coordinates. Alternatively if you must work entirely in unprojected lat-lng, then use `method='balltree'`.